# Is this a reasonable pattern for implementing NSMutableCopying?

Tags: objective-c, nscopying, nsmutablecopying

I'm looking to implement the `NSMutableCopying` interface as I have a set of objects which are immutable, but I also need to be able to create modified copies. Let's assume we've got a movie defined something like this (of course, really there would be more properties):

```
// BBMovie.h

@interface BBMovie : NSObject < NSCopying, NSMutableCopying >
@property(readonly, nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@end

@interface BBMutableMovie : BBMovie
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@end
```

From what I've read, if you need to set the ivars outside the constructor, as I will here to implement `NSCopying`, then it's good practice to define private setters for them. So I'd end up with an implementation like this for `BBMovie` (note that these types are not designed to allow subclassing):

```
// BBMovie.m (note: compiling with ARC)

@interface BBMovie ()
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@end

@implementation BBMovie
@synthesize title = _title;

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    BBMovie *copy = [[BBMovie allocWithZone:zone] init];
    if (copy) copy.title = self.title;
    return copy;
}

- (id)mutableCopyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    BBMutableMovie *copy = [[BBMutableMovie allocWithZone:zone] init];
    if (copy) copy.title = self.title;
    return copy;
}

@end
```

Now, given that I know the `BBMovie` implementation has both getters and setters for the properties, it seems like I should be able to implement `BBMutableMovie` as simply as:

```
@implementation BBMutableMovie
@dynamic title;
@end
```

Is there any problem with this approach, and/or am I missing anything?

Of course I realise that the BBMovie implementation isn't truly immutable as it will respond to the set messages if sent by consumers of the library, but that isn't really a concern to me as it doesn't present a security risk and falls outside 'normal' usage of the library.